# Can't use SearchTerm term = new MessageIDTerm(ID) to search mail by message-ID

Tags: jakarta-mail

Iam developing an Email application on Android and I got stuck at here. If I use Gmail server I can search Email by ID

```
  SearchTerm term = new MessageIDTerm(ID);
  message_s = folder.search(term);
```

But with this code, I can't search email with some Other server like yahoo,hotmail. And I try solve this bug by override this code

```
SearchTerm messageIDTerm= new SearchTerm() {
@Override
 public boolean match(Message message) {
 try {
    String   messageID="";
Enumeration headers = message.getAllHeaders();

   while (headers.hasMoreElements()) {
    eader h = (Header) headers.nextElement();               
    String mID = h.getName();                
    if(mID.contains("Message-ID") || mID.contains("Message-Id")){
    messageID= h.getValue();
    }
    }
    if (messageID.contains(ID)) {
     return true;
    }
    } catch (MessagingException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
    }
    };
   message_s = folder.search(messageIDTerm);
```

It's success to search mail. But the problem is this code check every Message-ID by client search(download messeage-ID and compare) and it take a lot of time to find the result.

The first way, server make a seach for my request and its very fast.

So how do I make the search as fast as the first way if I use the second way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some servers are broken.  You can't fix them.

If you have to do the search in the client, the best you can do is use the Folder.fetch method to prefetch the headers you're going to need to do the search.  Then use the standard MessageIDTerm with the Message.match method as you iterate over all the messages you need to check.

Comment: I try to use fetch but It still  takes long time to find messages-ID

Comment: Yup.  I recommend complaining to the owners of the broken mail servers.

Comment: I think there is no way to make server do a search instead of client.So I must find another solution to get body mail with some headers. Thanks for your help.