# How to get body of mail by message-ID or any header

Tags: search, jakarta-mail

I'm creating an email app. To save time, I just download subject and some header and saved them to database, not download body of mail.
And then, If user click on subject, I will download body of this mail.
I try to use Message-ID (because it's unique) to make it is an index. and Using this code to find this mail on server

```
 SearchTerm term = new MessageIDTerm(ID);
 message_s = folder.search(term);
```

But it just success on GMAIL, some other server, this code doesn't work correct.
I try to get All message-ID and compare it on client side, It toke a lot of time to find, user can't wait too long to get body of email.
**Anyone has an idea to find and download body of email correctly by Message-ID or by any header ?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't use SearchTerm term = new MessageIDTerm(ID) to search mail by message-ID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19486117/cant-use-searchterm-term-new-messageidtermid-to-search-mail-by-message-id)

Comment: Hi. I think it is not duplicate. As you said, some server doesn't support search by message-ID. I wrote this question to find some help to find out solution how to search and download body of mail if we have some header, I think we shouldn't search by client side, it took too long to find, so it's not a good solution.
Thanks